# Duplicate class com.adcolony.sdk.AdColony found in modules

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

I have two mediation networks in my project
IronSource for Interstitial and RewardedAd
AddApptr for Banner ads

So I implemented the librarys in my build.gradle but I get many build errors like this:

```
Duplicate class com.adcolony.adcolonysdk.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-AdColony-4.1.0-runtime.jar (com.intentsoftware.addapptr.subsdk:AdColony:4.1.0) and jetified-sdk-3.3.8-runtime.jar (com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.8)
```

I understand whats the problem here but I have no Idea how to fix it.
I already tried some solutions from the internet, I tried for example to search the "com.intentsoftware.addapptr.subsdk:AdColony:4.1.0" library under External Librarys, changed the class.jar to a class.zip and deleted all of the duplicated classes in there, in this example the com.adcolony.adcolonysdk.BuildConfig.class.
But as soon as I run the project it generates these deleted files again, so it doesnt change anything.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    //IronSource
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.10.1@jar'
    //Applovin
    implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:applovinadapter:4.3.5@jar'


    //Adcolony
    implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:adcolonyadapter:4.1.8@jar'
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.8'

    //UnityAds
    implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.1.4@jar'


    //Chartboost
    implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:chartboostadapter:4.1.9@jar'


    //Amazon
    implementation 'com.ironsource.adapters:amazonadapter:4.3.0@jar'


//AddApptr
    implementation ('com.intentsoftware.addapptr:AATKit:2.26.17') {
        transitive = true

    }
```

I also tried to exclude these duplicated classes like this:

```
implementation ('com.intentsoftware.addapptr:AATKit:2.26.17') {
    transitive = true
    exclude module: 'jetified-AdColony-4.1.0-runtime.jar'
}
```

but this also didnt worked.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I am very curios about this because i have same duplicate problem with jetified-chartboost

Comment: found the solution?